# Want to make each tuple point to a different link, how do i do it?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Basically, I want to make each tuple point to different URL so that I can view the semesters of the clicked department, and I am viewing this in a table.

I tried passing an href tag before echo in this code, but that is taking me to the same link when I press any tuple in the table.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<table border="1" id="table">

  <p>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#9999FF">Departements</th>
      </>
    </tr>

    <?php $servername="localhost" ; $username="root" ; $password="" ; $dbname="dbms_pro" ; // Create connection $conn=n ew mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } $sql = "SELECT dep_name FROM department"; $result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "
    <tr>
      <td department:>" . $row["dep_name"]. "</tr>
    </td>"; } } else { echo "0 results"; } $conn->close(); ?>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: you've a lot of commented code `$conn=n ew mysqli` for instance and there's a space in there, and this is invalid syntax `<td department:>`

Answer (score 1):

There is basically one tag in html to make hyperlinks and it is a (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp):

```
    <a href=""></a>
```

You need to iterate over array and add a unique id to href attribute to make what you want. Example code below, however it's not good to mix html and php in one file.

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table border="1" id="table">
      <p>
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="#9999FF">Departements</th>
          </>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ($departements as $row) {
            echo "
        <tr>
          <td><a href='/department/{$row["id"]}'>{$row["dep_name"]}</tr>
        </td>"; 
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: don't use w3fools as a citation source. just because they come up first in google results doesn't mean they're a good resource, it just means they wasted a ton of money on SEO instead of improving their content.

Comment: What source is better to use?

Comment: mozilla's MDN site is very good, or you could go straight to the source and link to the W3C html specs.